# adding environment variable inside kubernetes config file

Tags: kubernetes, kubeconfig

I am trying to set my company proxy inside my KUBECONFIG file hoping it would be picked up when i run kubectl from command line. I have tried many things but nothing helps so far. Here is the my config file.

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: 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
    server: https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
  name: cluster-ctdozjqhfqt
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: cluster-ctdozjqhfqt
    namespace: xxxxxxxxxx
    user: user-ctdozjqhfqt
  name: context-ctdozjqhfqt
current-context: context-ctdozjqhfqt
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: user-ctdozjqhfqt
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - ce
      - cluster
      - generate-token
      - --cluster-id
      - xxxxxxx
      - --region
      - xxxxxxxx
      - --profile
      - xxxxxxxx
      command: xxxx
      env:
       - name: HTTP_PROXY
         value: "http://xxxxxxx"
       - name: HTTPS_PROXY
         value: "http://xxxxx"
```

If I set the same environment variable on my terminal and run kubectl again, it just works. Am i missing something or doing something wrong in my config file?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the PR - [kubernetes-proxy-kubeconfig](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/81443).

This PR could help people accessing Cloud KubeContext that needs an explicit proxy, while local context like `Minikube` / `docker-desktop` / OnPremise should not use the explicit proxy (a very logic 502 bad gateway).

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

Supporting streaming endpoints over socks5 proxy is more involved, however it seems like this would be useful for many people using standard http proxies.

Take a look: [http-proxy-kubeconfig](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/351), [kubernetes-proxy-setup-kubeconfig](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/351).

Comment: i could not figure out which parameter under which section of kubeconfig file needs to be added. it seems there is no documentation for that.